# Reload Page In PHP To Display Image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, setinterval

I have a code in PHP like this:

```
<div class="row" id="buttons">
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $path = 'miniatura' . $camera_array[$i]['cameraId'] . '.jpeg';
        $fp = fopen($path, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $get_miniature);
        fclose($fp);
        echo '<div class="thumbnail" style="float:left;display:inline;" id="little"><img src="' . $path . '"/></div>';
    } 
?>
</div>
```

I want to reload `DIV` with my code to refresh the picture in 5 seconds. On the Internet I was found the JQuery `load()` method and wrote this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
        {
            $('#buttons').load(location.href+ " #little");
        },5000);
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong? Please help.

Comment: Just to eliminate one possibility - are you testing it using http(s) protocol, not file protocol? Can you see failed request in browsers network tab in dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleteing the white space before `" #little"`

`$('#buttons').load(location.href+ "#little");`

Comment: It still didn't work. Now it's loading the whole page to this div. Does it matter if page is on WordPress CMS?